# Call python script before build in a Jenkins job

Tags: python, plugins, build, jenkins

In a Jenkins job, I would want to call a Python script before the build. Ideally, between two plugins (Mercurial and Reviewbot).

Is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily call any **build step** before your "build" step. Just select the new build step from the menu, and drag it above the current one.

However, if you want to call a step before the **SCM checkout** (you mentioned Mercurial), you need a **[pre-scm-buildstep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep)**

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin called pre-scm-buildstep can help
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While the link may be helpful, it is generally recommended to include most important parts of what is needed to answer the question to your post directly. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer